# Rails: Efficient query for X objects before/after model in ranked list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model that has a position (or *score*, a float) in a ranked list. For example, I have:

Object A, score 27.7

Object B, score 20.3

Object C, score 15.3

where A would be considered to have position #1, B is #2 and C is #3 in the ranked list.

I'm trying to efficiently determine the position of any object based on their score, and X objects that are above/below that object. Is there a gem or query I can construct do this? I could load all the objects and iterate through them, but I'd like to find a more a efficient way of doing this since I have thousands of objects.

Comment: good point- PostgreSQL, but I'm open to a NoSQL solution if it's efficient/easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

It is all about tradeoffs (as is everything in this world).

1. Accuracy over efficiency.

   Simplest solution is to pull all records into memory and figure out rank there. Or you can write a not-so-complicated SQL query.
2. Efficiency over accuracy.

   Precalculate rank (store it in a column) and run regular jobs to refresh it. Take this very site. League ranks are updated once a day. And it works pretty fast. :-)
3. Accuracy and efficiency over memory consumption and simplicity of administration.

   Set up an instance of [Redis](http://redis.io). It has fast operations on sorted sets. You will pay with more complicated code, more moving parts in your project and increased memory consumption.

Comment: I appreciate the discussion of trade-offs, it's well thought out and makes good points. However, I am more interested in concrete thoughts on the ways to query ActiveRecord to do this.

Comment: @eDave: I don't think you can achieve that in ActiveRecord (without going down to raw SQL)